# Web Request : How to determine the request' Content-Type?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

Before answering my question please understand the platform and the available resources.

I use: .NET c# 4.5 framework on windows 10.
I use CefSharp chromium based framework. Since some people is not familiar with cef, I specifically shared the handler class which I know I can get the request object to work with. I am focused  this method below:

```
   CefReturnValue IRequestHandler.OnBeforeResourceLoad(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IRequest request, IRequestCallback callback)
```

I want to achieve this list below: It is a clean list of content types: I thin I should convert mime types tot element type like this below (from request type of the appropriate handler's event)

```
 case 1:    return "script";
    case 2:    return "image";
    case 4:    return "background";
    case 8:    return "stylesheet";
    case 16:   return "object";
    case 32:   return "sub_frame";
    case 64:   return "object_subrequest";
    case 128:  return "media";
    case 256:  return "other";
    case 512:  return "xmlhttprequest";
    case 1024: return "main_frame";
    case 2048: return "elemhide";
    case 4096: return "popup";
    default:   return "selector";
```

To be more clear I want to give an example:
Imagine I run chrome web browser , and I entered www.hurriyet.com.tr

If I debug this on handlers class; I see main domain:  www.hurriyet.com.tr  and several requests from other domains like syndication.google.com/sub/main.html

As you see this is one request and the url is "syndication.google.com/sub/main.html" so it is a sub-frame

another request till page is loaded; the second request is "adspub.mediacatatogry.com/img/banner.gif" as you see, this is a image request.

Please help me to get correct content type for each request. I want to classify those request according to referenced list above..

Thank you.

**Excerpt from handler class:**

```
// Copyright © 2010-2016 The CefSharp Authors. All rights reserved.
//
// Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be found in the LICENSE file.

using System;
using CefSharp.Example.Filters;

namespace CefSharp.Example
{
    public class RequestHandler : IRequestHandler
    {    
        CefReturnValue IRequestHandler.OnBeforeResourceLoad(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IRequest request, IRequestCallback callback)
        {
            //Example of how to set Referer
            // Same should work when setting any header

            // For this example only set Referer when using our custom scheme
            var url = new Uri(request.Url);
            if (url.Scheme == CefSharpSchemeHandlerFactory.SchemeName)
            {
                var headers = request.Headers;

                headers["Referer"] = "http://google.com";

                request.Headers = headers;
            }

            //NOTE: If you do not wish to implement this method returning false is the default behaviour
            // We also suggest you explicitly Dispose of the callback as it wraps an unmanaged resource.
            //callback.Dispose();
            //return false;

            //NOTE: When executing the callback in an async fashion need to check to see if it's disposed
            if (!callback.IsDisposed)
            {
                using (callback)
                {
                    if (request.Method == "POST")
                    {
                        using (var postData = request.PostData)
                        {
                            if(postData != null)
                            { 
                                var elements = postData.Elements;

                                var charSet = request.GetCharSet();

                                foreach (var element in elements)
                                {
                                    if (element.Type == PostDataElementType.Bytes)
                                    {
                                        var body = element.GetBody(charSet);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    //Note to Redirect simply set the request Url
                    //if (request.Url.StartsWith("https://www.google.com", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                    //{
                    //    request.Url = "https://github.com/";
                    //}

                    //Callback in async fashion
                    //callback.Continue(true);
                    //return CefReturnValue.ContinueAsync;
                }
            }

            return CefReturnValue.Continue;
        }
    }
}
```

What do you think, they have a switch case block? so how to group these mime types in to this specific list above.. Any idea?

Comment: Was it really necessary to include the source for the whole example `RequestHandler`? Rather than trying to paint a picture can you be more concise about your question? I've read it twice and I'm still unclear on what your asking. I'd also suggest tagging your question with `CefSharp`, it's only the fact that I occasionally check the `chromium-embedded` tag that I saw this.

Comment: Sir. @amitland; warm regards from istanbul. I follow every step of talking about request handlers on cefsharp3 . I want to build up a half-generic extension for adblock extension for chrome. I am very close to build up this. I had some good performance and results. This is required to have a full adapted extension for the first time of cefsharp extension examples...

Comment: Greetings, sounds like your working on something interesting! Best place to discuss such things is the `CefSharp Gitter Channel`. As per your question, so it's just the `ResourceType` you need? http://magpcss.org/ceforum/apidocs3/projects/%28default%29/CefRequest.html#GetResourceType%28%29 Unfortunately that's not currently exposed, I created issue https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/1605 to track the task. If you have some time, you can quite easily implement the required changes.

Comment: https://gitter.im/cefsharp/CefSharp#

Comment: Sir. @amaitland . Thanks for your coordination and strong help. I have subscribed to the ticket. And IF i have time I will pull my req. fyi.

Comment: Ok great, comment on the issue if you have any questions about how to make the changes, should take about 15mins to implement.

Comment: We implemented it. And I saw it is working. how can i pull it?

Comment: See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Forking-and-Pull-Requests for some info on working with `Git/GitHub`.